# summary statistics in scala

Tags: scala, statistics, summary

How can I elegantly calculate summary statistics (e.g. mean variance) elegantly in scala per group here in this example per each different metric(name)?

```
case class MeasureUnit(name: String, value: Double)

Seq(MeasureUnit("metric1", 0.04), MeasureUnit("metric1", 0.09),
  MeasureUnit("metric2", 0.64), MeasureUnit("metric2", 0.34), MeasureUnit("metric2", 0.84))
```

An excellent example how to calculate mean /variance per property is https://chrisbissell.wordpress.com/2011/05/23/a-simple-but-very-flexible-statistics-library-in-scala/
but that does not cover the grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Seq#groupBy](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@groupBy[K](f:A=%3EK):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,Repr])

```
val measureSeq : Seq[MeasureUnit] = ???

type Name = String

// "metric1" -> Seq(0.04, 0.09), "metric2" -> Seq(0.64, 0.34, 0.84)
val groupedMeasures : Map[Name, Seq[Double]] = 
  measureSeq
    .groupBy(_.name)
    .mapValues(_ map (_.value))
```

The groupings can then be used to calculate your summary statistics:

```
type Mean = Double

val meanMapping : Map[Name, Mean] = 
  groupedMeasures mapValues { v => mean(v) }

type Variance = Double

val varianceMapping : Map[Name, Variance] = 
  groupedMeasures mapValues { v => variance(v) }
```

Or you can map each name to a tuple of statistics:

```
type Summary = Tuple2[Mean, Variance]

val summaryMapping : Map[Name, Summary] = 
  groupedMeasures mapValues {s => (mean(s), variance(s)) }
```

Comment: This looks great. However, for me, I get `not found value mean` for the mean and respective variance. Do I need to define these according to the link? Or do they need to be imported from somewhere /implement them myself? In case they should be from the link see which fails because no implicit mapping is available: https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/bf944a9ac04d20973c479057128c7fd2

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the functions that were defined in the link.  Based on the docs in the link they are using many implicit converters for the functions to work.  You'll need all of the converters in scope for compilation to complete, e.g. you need to import the `Numeric[T]` typeclass.

Comment: Sorry for asking again. What am I missing if `val meanMapping: Map[Name, Mean] = groupedMeasures mapValues mean` fails with aforementioned problem but `mean(groupedMeasures.get("metric1").get)` works just fine?

Comment: No apologies necessary.  Perhaps the implicit isn't working.  I've updated my answer with a slightly different syntax.  see if that works...

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. Would I need to import infix operators to make the other solution work?

Comment: No there's nothing to import.  The `mean` function takes an implicit `Numeric[T]`.  Apparently writing the `mapValues` using infix takes away the implicit passing...